# PHP - Mysql query: Display number of orders by day and store in variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with this structure:

```
table name: customer_history

id| orders | order_date (timestamp) |  status    |  
--------------------------------------------------
 1|   1    | 2012-05-29 13:11:59    |  active    |
 2|   1    | 2012-05-29 13:11:59    |  active    |
 3|   1    | 2012-05-30 13:11:59    |  canceled  |
 4|   1    | 2012-05-31 13:11:59    |  trialing  |
```

I need to query the db and count the number of total orders, where status != canceled, for each day, going back one calendar month, and assign a unique variable to each daily total.

Yesterday's order total would be something like $day-1, two days ago $day-2, etc.

**EDIT** Answer below.

```
$query = "SELECT 
            COUNT(*) AS number, 
            DATE(order_date) AS order_day 
        FROM 
            customer_history
        WHERE 
            status <> 'canceled' 
        GROUP BY 
            order_day 
        ORDER BY 
            order_date 
        DESC
        LIMIT 31";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$i = 1;
$days = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $days[$i] = $row;
      $i++;
}

echo $days[1]['number'];
echo $days[2]['number'];
echo $days[3]['number'];
echo $days[4]['number'];
echo $days[5]['number'];
echo $days[6]['number'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number, DATE(order_date) AS order_day FROM orders WHERE status <> 'canceled' GROUP BY order_day ORDER BY order_date DESC LIMIT 31
```

Then just loop over the results. First one is the current day, second is yesterday, third is day before yesterday, etc.

**EDIT**

Including loop/variables:

```
    <?php

$query = "SELECT 
                COUNT(*) AS number, 
                DATE(order_date) AS order_day 
            FROM 
                orders 
            WHERE 
                status <> 'canceled' 
            GROUP BY 
                order_day 
            ORDER BY 
                order_date 
            DESC
            LIMIT 31";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $i = 1;
    $days = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
    {
        $days[$i] = $row;
        $i++;

    }

    ?>
```

echo $days[1]['number'] gives you the number of orders for today, $days[2]['number'] for yesterday, etc. You can output the actual date by echoing $days[x]['order_day'].

Comment: The loop and setting the variables are the main things giving me trouble.  Can you elaborate?  My first time working with mysql...

Comment: Where do I specify the table name (customer_history)?

Comment: Wait, maybe I don't get your data model. What's the consumer_history table about? Is there a normal orders table?

Comment: Hmmm.  Each customer has an id, order, status, and order date. I'm trying to get # of orders from each day.  The table just happens to be called customer_history.  Perhaps we skype?

Comment: Try changing 'orders' to 'customer_history' in that case.

Comment: It queries the table fine, however, the array $days[i]['number'] is blank...  And there are orders in the db.

Comment: Does the query return any results at all? Did you run it in PHPMyAdmin or a similar program?

Comment: See what var_dump($days) says, I'm confident all data is there.

Comment: I figured out the problem and updated my edit. the mysql_fetch_assoc was referring to the $query, not the $result. When I changed it, voilà!  Thanks for helping me trouble shoot.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query with `GROUP BY order_date`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number, DATE(order_date) AS order_day
FROM orders WHERE status != 'canceled' 
GROUP BY order_date ORDER BY order_date DESC
```